# Combine 2 images side by side into 1 with ImageMagick (PHP)

Tags: php, imagemagick

I think this is an easy one.

I have 2 Pictures/JPGs and i want them to merge into one picture where the 2 are side by side.

So i have pic [A] and pic [B] and I want to get pic [AB] (side by side).

Both images have same width and height. In this case width=200px and height=300px. *But the 2nd Image should appear on position 200,0 .. also when imagewidth is smaller than 200px (200px is maxwidth)*

This is what I've tried (php):

```
exec($IMAGEMAGICK_PATH."composite picA.jpg -geometry +200+0 picB.jpg picAB.jpg");
```

I also tried the same with "-size 400x300" after "composite" but nothing happens.
Problem is that the image picA.jpg is moved 200px and merged into picB.jpg, but the width of picAB.jpg is the same as picB.jpg is.

I'm also not sure if "-geometry" is the correct command.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20737061/merge-images-side-by-sidehorizontally | https://superuser.com/questions/290656/combine-multiple-images-using-imagemagick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a commandline to do the image appending due to the extended requirements, where the right picture should be offset by 200 pixels from the left edge, regardless of the (smaller) width of the left image:

```
 convert                          \
   -background '#FFF9E3'          \
    xc:none -resize 200x1\!       \
    right+narrow.png -append      \
    left+wider.png                \
   -gravity south                 \
   +append                        \
   -crop '400x +0+1'              \
   +repage                        \
    result.png
```

The part `xc:none -resize 200x1\!` creates a 1 pixel high, 200 pixels long line and vertically appends the smaller (right) image to it.

To this intermediate result the horizontally appending of the wider (left) image happens. We would now have a 401x100 picture with a maybe ugly line of transparent pixels on top.

That's why we shave off this top pixel line with the `-crop` function.

You should be able to translate that into PHP yourself... :-)

Answer (score 14):

No need to use `-geometry` if both files are the same size. Try

```
exec($IMAGEMAGICK_PATH."convert picA.jpg picB.jpg +append picAB.jpg");
```

Use `-append` if you want to merge pictures in a column.

Add `-background none` or `-background black` or `-background white` or whatever, if your pictures are **not** the same size. In this case you may also want to add `-gravity center` or `-gravity south` or some such to control how exactly the two images merge. The `-gravity` needs to appear before the `+-append` on the commandline then:

```
exec($IMAGEMAGICK_PATH."convert big.jpg small.jpg -gravity east -append 2x.jpg");
```

Comment: hey thanks. that's it. but what i forgot: if my pictures are smaller than 200px i want the picB.jpg to appear after 200px from 0,0 .. so that there is a whitespace between the two merged pix. Can I do this with geometry?

Comment: @JohnDoeSmith: what background color do you want for the 'gap'?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you'll find the `montage` method easier to understand (this is probably what you had in mind when you tried it with `composite` -- but that one is for *overlapping* images, not for side-by-side montage...)

```
montage                 \
  -background '#FFF9E3' \
  -geometry 200\!x\>    \
  -gravity west         \
   right+narrow.jpg     \
   left+wider.jpg       \
   result.jpg
```

Answer (score 3):

Here the PHP Code I use at Kinoulink (a french start-up) :

```
$im1 = new \Imagick($media1);
$im2 = new \Imagick($media2);
$imTotal = new \Imagick();

$im1->cropthumbnailimage(62, 128);
$im2->cropthumbnailimage(62, 128);

$imTotal->newimage(128, 128, '#ffffffff');

$imTotal->compositeimage($im1, \Imagick::COMPOSITE_DEFAULT, 0, 0);
$imTotal->compositeimage($im2, \Imagick::COMPOSITE_DEFAULT, 66, 0);

$imTotal->writeimage($albumCoverFilePath);
```