# Two Images Become One

Tags: php, image, imagemagick

I want a user to be able to upload two different images, then join them side by side and have the result saved as a single image file.

I've looked into [this](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.flattenimages.php), but;

1. I don't understand it.
2. It seems to lay one image on top of the other.

I need them side by side, then saved as one file.

Thoughts?

Comment: http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/layers/#append

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12076293/combine-2-images-side-by-side-into-1-with-imagemagick-php) answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this? http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.appendimages.php
(if you insist on using imagick that is)

Comment: I have checked this link but i am not understand. please give more answer

Comment: This seems like what I need, but I'm definitely not married to "imagick" and I really don't know how to use it.  I tried using the example code given at that link and I got...
<br/><br/>

**Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/gtilflm/public_html/img.php:2) in /home/gtilflm/public_html/img.php on line 18
‰PNG  IHDR,2›¸¹gAMA±üasRGB®Îé cHRMz&€„ú€èu0ê`:˜pœºQ< PLTEÿ€ÿVÈº” pHYsHHFÉk>,IDATHÇíÌ1 •´¤)M°×4Ól—Ëår¹\.—Ëår¹ž¯2bÝ[‚‹È¥IEND®B`‚**

Any ideas?

Comment: Sure. You have a call to header(...) function somewhere in img.php, and it conflicts with header("Content-Type: image/png") from the example code. Just make sure you call header(...) only once in the script... Also, the example code doesn't actually save your file as you probably want, but rather tries to send it to browser as a result of your PHP script. To alter that behaviour, instead of header(...) and echo(...) you'd have to use this http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.writeimage.php

Answer (score 0):

Hi mate please try below code it will help you.

```
<?php

header ("Content-type: image/png");
$src = array ("http://img164.imageshack.us/img164/5175/toprb3.jpg","http://img123.imageshack.us/img123/9056/leftij4.jpg");   
$imgBuf = array ();
foreach ($src as $link)
{
   switch(substr ($link,strrpos ($link,".")+1))
   {
       case 'png':
           $iTmp = imagecreatefrompng($link);
           break;
       case 'gif':
           $iTmp = imagecreatefromgif($link);
           break;               
       case 'jpeg':           
       case 'jpg':
           $iTmp = imagecreatefromjpeg($link);
           break;               
   }
   array_push ($imgBuf,$iTmp);
}
$iOut = imagecreatetruecolor ("450","131") ;
imagecopy ($iOut,$imgBuf[0],0,0,0,0,imagesx($imgBuf[0]),imagesy($imgBuf[0]));
imagedestroy ($imgBuf[0]);
imagecopy ($iOut,$imgBuf[1],0,54,0,0,imagesx($imgBuf[1]),imagesy($imgBuf[1]));
imagedestroy ($imgBuf[1]);

imagepng($iOut);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks Praveen.  I've implemented your script, but I need the images to be side-by-side, not in a top-down orientation.  How can I adjust the script to achieve that?

Comment: Hello john you just need to adjust the parameter of imagecopy function i mean just x,y coordinate.